# Creating multiple files from a single source file

Tags: c

I am currently learning C and trying to solve a problem. I have a text file name `elements.txt` which has the following:

**elements.txt**

```
Carbon (from Latin: carbo "coal") is a chemical element  ..

Oxygen is a chemical element with symbol O ..

Platinum is a chemical element with symbol Pt ...

Silicon is a chemical element with symbol Si ...

Titanium is a chemical element with symbol Ti ...
```

I would like to create multiple files based on elements such as `carbon.txt`, `oxygen.txt`, `platinum.txt`, `silicon.txt` and `titanium.txt` from `elements.txt`.

This is my soure code:

```
  void magic(){
  FILE *fp,*fp1, *fp2, *fp3, *fp4, *fp5;
  char *fn, *fn1, *fn2, *fn3, *fn4, *fn5;
  int ch;

  fn1 = "new/carbon.txt";
  fn2 = "new/oxygen.txt";
  fn3 = "new/platinum.txt";
  fn4 = "new/silicon.txt";
  fn5 = "new/titanium.txt";

  fn = "elements.txt";

  // Read file
  fp = fopen(fn ,"r");
  if(fp == NULL){
    printf("Error opening %s for reading. Program terminated",fn);
  }

  // Write file
  fp1 = fopen(fn1, "w");
  fp2 = fopen(fn2, "w");
  fp3 = fopen(fn3, "w");
  fp4 = fopen(fn4, "w");
  fp5 = fopen(fn5, "w");

  if(fp1 == NULL || fp2 == NULL || fp3 == NULL || fp4 == NULL || fp5 == NULL){
    printf("Error opening %s for wrting. Program terminated",fn);
  }

  while( (ch= fgetc(fp)) != '\n')
    fputc(ch, fp1);

  while( (ch= fgetc(fp)) != '\n')
    fputc(ch, fp2);

  while( (ch= fgetc(fp)) != '\n')
    fputc(ch, fp3);

  while( (ch= fgetc(fp)) != '\n')
    fputc(ch, fp4);

  while( (ch= fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    fputc(ch, fp5);

  printf("All files were created successfuly!.\n");
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    fclose(fp3);
    fclose(fp4);
    fclose(fp5);
    fclose(fp);
}



  int main(){
    magic();
    return 0;
  }
```

I do get my files created but oxygen gets printed in platinum and platinum,silicon and titanium gets printed in titanium. It seems like there is a mistake,when I am doing a while loop reading the character. Not sure how to fix this issue.And is there a way to read multiple and write multiple files using for-loop?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!thanks

Comment: "Program terminated" The program is lying...

Comment: Deal with the blank lines in the input properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.txt` input file, contents for different elements are separated by *two* newline characters, not one. Try rewrite it:

```
Carbon is... 
Oxygen is...
```

etc. (without extra newline at the end of a paragraph).

Alternatively, you can check for the presence of 2 newlines instead of 1, but this will be more complicated.

(Explanations: The program writes about carbon to `fn1`, then sees a newline and switches to `fn2`, *then sees another newline* and switches to `fn3`. The same thing happens at the end of the oxygen paragraph).

Answer (score 2):

As comments suggest, in order to make this block correct, you should add a `return` statement:

```
 if(fp1 == NULL || fp2 == NULL || fp3 == NULL || fp4 == NULL || fp5 == NULL){
    printf("Error opening %s for wrting. Program leaving",fn);
    return; //add this statement to leave function
  }
```

Otherwise, the statement *Program terminated* will be a lie.

If you want your code to handle input files that have lines with only spaces (instead of modifying your input files), add a test for lines with only spaces before putting that line in your output file.  Using `fgets()`, `strstr()` and `strlen()` would be suited to creating such a test.

Comment: More appropriate would be `exit(1)` or something similar, to indicate a nonzero exit code for the operating system.

Comment: @hyst329 - `return` allows for other things to be done from the calling function. In this case, `main()` exits in the very next step, but that is not always the case.

Comment: or change the type of `magic()` to `int` and then `return 1;`. `void` return type isn't very good here, because it doesn't provide any information to `main()`

Comment: @hyst329 - agree'd - Good suggestion.  You should add that to your answer. :)